# Sending messages to home PC and back from Android/iOS Unity app

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, websocket, cloud, publish-subscribe

looking for tips and recommendations.

I'm building a Unity Android/iOS app that sends a message (string, approx 100 chars ) to my PC GPU at home using my Windows 10 with Python to do an AI job. Then my PC would send a message ( string, about 20 chars) back to the client within about a 10 seconds to 1 minutes of receiving it,when task is done.
If more clients send messages they would queue up on my PC/server.

Looking for a cloud service, "middle man" such as Azure, AWS.. etc. but I do not know exactly which of all those services or protocols that they offer would fit.
I estimate on a good day 5000 messages sent and maybe 20 concurrent users at most.

I've read up on Websockets, Push-subscribe... just haven't been able to decide which fits. Thanks!

I tried short-polling to a Mysql database on my web hosting server but they don't allow so many repeated requests.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SNS  or SQS would fit to your use case.

https://aws.amazon.com/sns/
https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

SNS pushes messages and SQS polls a queue. It's up to you which one to select. Perhaps this article helps you to make the decision:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-messaging-services-for-serverless-applications/